# Group contiguous blocks for aggregation in SQL (Redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I've got a table like this:

```
    id time activity
 1:  1    1        a
 2:  1    2        a
 3:  1    3        b
 4:  1    4        b
 5:  1    5        a
 6:  2    1        a
 7:  2    2        b
 8:  2    3        b
 9:  2    4        b
10:  2    5        a
11:  2    6        a
12:  2    7        c
13:  2    8        c
14:  2    9        c
```

Within each `id`, I would like to aggregate by contiguous blocks of `activity`. So essentially I want a `grouping` column like this:

```
    id time activity grouping
 1:  1    1        a        1
 2:  1    2        a        1
 3:  1    3        b        2
 4:  1    4        b        2
 5:  1    5        a        3
 6:  2    1        a        1
 7:  2    2        b        2
 8:  2    3        b        2
 9:  2    4        b        2
10:  2    5        a        3
11:  2    6        a        3
12:  2    7        c        4
13:  2    8        c        4
14:  2    9        c        4
```

So that I can use aggregate functions and get something like this:

```
select id
, min(time) as min_time
, max(time) as max_time
, count(*) as n_activity
from A
group by id, grouping

   id min_time max_time n_activity
1:  1        1        2          2
2:  1        3        4          2
3:  1        5        5          1
4:  2        1        1          1
5:  2        2        4          3
6:  2        5        6          2
7:  2        7        9          3
```

How can I create the grouping column? My table is quite large, so I would prefer to avoid cursor functions if possible.

---

Some sample data:

```
create table A (id int, time int, activity varchar);
insert into A (id, time, activity)
values
(1,1,'a'),(1,2,'a'),(1,3,'b'),(1,4,'b'),(1,5,'a'),(2,1,'a'),
(2,2,'b'),(2,3,'b'),(2,4,'b'),(2,5,'a'),(2,6,'a'),(2,7,'c'),
(2,8,'c'),(2,9,'c')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lag` to check if the previous row has the same activity as current, if it isn't reset it with a running sum.

```
select t.*,sum(case when prev_activity=activity then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by id order by time) as grp
from (
select t.*,lag(activity) over(partition by id order by time) as prev_activity
from tbl t
) t
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks! I had been using `lag` to pull the first row of each block, which met half my needs, but I couldn't make the jump with the running sum.

Comment: This works in postgre, but I can't seem to translate it to Redshift. Redshift requires a `frame` statement for the windowed sum, and I can't find a suitable solution. `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` puts the last row of a group with the next group, and `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` leaves the first row of each group blank. Any ideas?

Comment: `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` should work as expected in my opinion.

Comment: Ah, yes it does. My issue is one of data quality (tied times with different activities). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to just use the `time` value and a secondary sequence of numbers from `ROW_NUMBER()`?

```
SELECT
  *,
  time - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, activity
                                ORDER BY time        )   AS rownum
FROM
  yourTable
```

The fields `(id,activity,rownum)` the gives a composite key for your groups.

You can then wrap `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rownum, activity DESC)` aroudn the whole thing, if you really need it as a single field identifier.

```
    id time activity   rownum  (time-rownum) (composite key) (dense_rank)

 1:  1    1        a    1                  0         (1,a,0)       1
 2:  1    2        a    2                  0         (1,a,0)       1
 3:  1    3        b      1                2         (1,b,2)       2
 4:  1    4        b      2                2         (1,b,2)       2
 5:  1    5        a    3                  2         (1,a,2)       3

 6:  2    1        a    1                  0         (2,a,0)       1
 7:  2    2        b      1                1         (2,b,1)       2
 8:  2    3        b      2                1         (2,b,1)       2
 9:  2    4        b      3                1         (2,b,1)       2
10:  2    5        a    2                  3         (2,a,3)       3
11:  2    6        a    3                  3         (2,a,3)       3
12:  2    7        c        1              6         (2,c,6)       4
13:  2    8        c        2              6         (2,c,6)       4
14:  2    9        c        3              6         (2,c,6)       4
```

Applying the composite key to your aggregation example...

```
SELECT
    id
  , min(time) as min_time
  , max(time) as max_time
  , count(*) as n_activity
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    time - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, activity
                                  ORDER BY time        )   AS rownum
  FROM
    yourTable
)
  partitioned
GROUP BY
  id, activity, rownum
```

If time is sorted, but not always contiguous, that becomes...

```
SELECT
    id
  , min(time) as min_time
  , max(time) as max_time
  , count(*) as n_activity
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                           ORDER BY time        )
    -
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, activity
                           ORDER BY time        )   AS rownum
  FROM
    yourTable
)
  partitioned
GROUP BY
  id, activity, rownum
```

Comment: This use of the difference between two sequences as been known as a solution to a "gaps and islands" problem, and can be really handy in a lot of problem spaces!